# Android MutableLiveData not being reflected back to main activity UI

Tags: android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I've been trying to solve my problem by checking out similar questions here but to no avail. So I decided to post this.

Scenario: I have the following files, (MainActivity, FormActivity, DatabaseHelper, CounterViewModel). On app's open it hits the MainActivity and display a total count by requesting `getCounter` from **CounterViewModel**. When I go to **FormActivity** to update the counter, its saves into the SQLite via the **DatabaseHelper** class and in there, I call the `setCounter` to update the value. But when the application goes back to MainActivity UI after saving the counter, the count is not updated.

**CounterViewModel**

```
public class CounterViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private String TAG = "=== " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " ===";
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> counter = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(int newCount) {
        counter.postValue(newCount);
        Log.d(TAG, "New count is " + newCount);
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
// this is located inside the onCreate()
CounterViewModel counterViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CounterViewModel.class);
LiveData<Integer> counter = counterViewModel.getCounter();

counter.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OBSERVED " + integer);
        labelScanTotal.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", integer));
    }
});
```

**DatabaseHelper**

```
// From the FormActivity the dbhelper.updateCount() is called. Below is the part where the ViewModel is called
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
CounterViewModel counterViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(mainActivity).get(CounterViewModel.class);
counterViewModel.setCounter(getCount());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change ViewModelProviders to ViewModelProvider

```
CounterViewModel counterViewModel =    ViewModelProviders.of(mainActivity).get(CounterViewModel.class);
```

to

```
CounterViewModel counterViewModel = ViewModelProvider.(this).get(CounterViewModel.class);
```

Comment: In the mainActivity where I display the counter I did this ```CounterViewModel counterViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CounterViewModel.class);``` which works but the update trigger is on the **DatabaseHelper** file where I need to call the ```CounterViewModel.setCounter```. But it only allows me to create ```new CounterViewModel``` again and when going back to MainActivity, it does not update. Maybe it's because of the **new**